# Open text file at runtime for manual editing

Tags: excel, vba, file, runtime

The code snippet below is modified from a larger project where I collect data from text files and output that data to an Excel Table (VBA listobject). The code loops through all the text files in a specified folder looking for files that match certain conditions. Valid files have a header containing the tag `## DATA FILE ##` on the first line, and some metadata on the next few lines. I am using the `FileSystemObject` from Microsoft Scripting Runtime to open those files and loop through line by line. For this example I assume that I have a text file in the folder `C:\MyFolder` with a valid tag on the first line, for example with the following content:

```
## DATA FILE ##
Version: 49

123 456 789 Some information
111 444 000 Further items
```

With this setup, the code below should execute smoothly and output "Test passed" to the immediate window. If the tag line is modified, the code should instead present a message box asking the user for further instructions.

Now, if a text file does not contain the necessary tag on the first line, I would like to add the option to manually open and edit that file in Notepad at runtime, and then continue execution. I've prepared a Yes-No-Cancel message box that can be used to decide what to do, but how can I open the file for manual editing at runtime?

```
Option Explicit

Sub LoopThroughFiles()
' Loops through text files looking for files matching some conditions.
' Files that match are processed further.
' For files that don't match, the user can choose to inspect and
' modify the source file.
' Requires that a reference is set to Tools -> References
'   -> Microsoft Scripting Runtime

    Dim FSO As FileSystemObject
    Dim TSO As TextStream
    Dim oFolder, oFile As Object
    Dim sFileName, sLine, sMsg As String
    Dim lMsg As Long
    Const sPath As String = "C:\MyFolder\"

    Set FSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set oFolder = FSO.GetFolder(sPath)

    ' Loop through files:
    For Each oFile In oFolder.Files
        sFileName = oFile.Name
        ' Treat only text files:
        If Right(sFileName, 4) = ".txt" Then
            Set TSO = FSO.OpenTextFile(sPath & sFileName, ForReading)
            ' Check that conditions are met:
            sLine = TSO.ReadLine
            If Not sLine = "## DATA FILE ##" Then
                sMsg = "The following file does not seem to " & _
                        "contain valid input data:" & vbNewLine & vbNewLine
                sMsg = sMsg & sFileName & vbNewLine & vbNewLine
                sMsg = sMsg & "Would you like to manually inspect " & _
                        "the file?" & vbNewLine & _
                        "(Click No to continue running the script " & _
                        "; Cancel to exit.)"
                lMsg = MsgBox(sMsg, vbYesNoCancel)
                Debug.Print lMsg
                Stop
                '
                ' OPTION HERE TO MANUALLY OPEN AND EDIT THE TEXT FILE IN NOTEPAD
                '
            Else
                Debug.Print "Test passed"
                ' Other code here to further process valid data.
            End If
            TSO.Close
        End If
    Next oFile
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Dim yourTextFile As String: yourTextFile = "C:\Sample.txt"

Call Shell("notepad.exe """ & yourTextFile & """", vbNormalFocus)
```

Use `Shell` to open a selected text file.

Comment: Exactly what I needed, thanks! +1 for the not-so-intuitive string concatenation that is omitted from the [documentation](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Shell-Function-FF2E4B1B-712D-4E34-AEA6-6832EADD3C63).